# Finding the last two digits of a number using Euler

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am using Euler's theorem to find the last two digits of $7^{91}$.

So this means I want to calculate $7^{91}\bmod100$. I have found $\phi(100)=40$ so $7^{40}\equiv 1\bmod100$.

This gives $7^{91}\equiv$$7^{{40}\cdot2}\cdot7^{11}$ which is just $7^{11}$ so I need to calculate $7^{11}\bmod100$.

I wanted to know if there was a way to simplify even further such as $7\cdot7^{10}$. I know the answer is $43$ by looking  $7^{11}\bmod100$ up but didn't know if I could just jump straight to this or I have to simplify it more first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify it  more first by noting that $7^4\equiv 1 \bmod 100$, so that
$7^{11}\equiv 7^3\equiv 43\bmod 100$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $7^4=2401$
So...$$7^{91}\equiv7^{88}\cdot7^3\equiv(1)^{88}\cdot343\equiv43 \pmod{100}$$

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese remainder theorem leads to an efficient solution:
$$ 7^{91} \equiv (-1)^{91} \equiv (-1) \equiv \color{blue}{3\!\!\!\!\!\pmod{4}} $$
$$ 7^{91} \equiv 7(49)^{45} \equiv 7(-1)^{45} \equiv (-7) \equiv \color{green}{18\!\!\!\!\pmod{25}} $$
hence by combining the green and blue results
$$ 7^{91}\equiv\color{red}{43\!\!\!\!\pmod{100}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a different approach,

$$\begin{align}
7^{11}&=7(3-10)^{10}\\
&\equiv7\cdot3^{10}\\
&=7\cdot9^5\\
&=7(10-1)^5\\
&\equiv7(50-1)\\
&=343\\
&\equiv43
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Simpler: mod $\,50\!:\ 7^{\large 91}\! = 7(7^{\large 2})^{\large 45}\!\equiv 7(-1)^{\large 45}\!\equiv -7,\,$ so mod $\,100\!:\ 7^{\large 91}\!\equiv 43\,$ or $\,93,\,$ necessarily $43$ since
mod $\,4\!:\ 7^{\large 91}\! \equiv (-1)^{\large 91}\! \equiv -1\equiv 43\not\equiv 93$.